# Parsing Time Series Data using D3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg, time-series, timeserieschart

It is time to ask for help. I have been studying D3.js for weeks and am just beginning to feel like I understand 10% of it (ha, ha, ha). I am trying to generate a very simple line graph. I am able to do this as long as the data is very simple, but my raw data source has UTC timestamps, and real/decimal numbers that keeps crashing anything beyond simple.

The raw data source looks like this:

```
{
  "Links": {},
  "Items": [
    {
      "Timestamp": "2016-07-12T22:21:10Z",
      "Value": 1055.6793212890625,
      "UnitsAbbreviation": "m3/h",
      "Good": true,
      "Questionable": false,
      "Substituted": false
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2016-07-12T22:39:10Z",
      "Value": 989.00830078125,
      "UnitsAbbreviation": "m3/h",
      "Good": true,
      "Questionable": false,
      "Substituted": false
    }
  ],
  "UnitsAbbreviation": "m3/h"
}
```

Using jQuery and a javascript time formatting function I am able to assemble the following simplified dataset:

```
var dataset = [
{'theTime': '2016/07/12 15:58:40', 'theValue': 1123.07275390625},
{'theTime': '2016/07/12 16:21:10', 'theValue': 1055.6793212890625},
{'theTime': '2016/07/12 16:45:40', 'theValue': 962.4850463867188},
{'theTime': '2016/07/12 17:14:40', 'theValue': 831.2259521484375},
{'theTime': '2016/07/12 17:55:10', 'theValue': 625.3046875}
];
```

Here is my code:

```
//~ Populate the 'dataset':
var dataset = [];
$.get(url, function(data){
    var itemCount = data.Items.length;
    var commaCount = itemCount - 1;
    for(i=0; i &#60; itemCount; i++){
        if(i == commaCount){
            dataset.push("{'theTime': '" + formattedDateTime(data.Items[i].Timestamp) + "', 'theValue': " + data.Items[i].Value + "}");
        }
        else {
        dataset.push("{'theTime': '" + formattedDateTime(data.Items[i].Timestamp) + "', 'theValue': " + data.Items[i].Value + "},");
    }
    }
        
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);
    
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);
    
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");
    
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");
    
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.theTime); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.theValue); });    
    
    var svg = d3.select("#myChart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
        dataset.forEach(function(d) {
            d.theTime = parseDate(d.theTime);
            d.theValue = +d.theValue;
         });
    
         x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.theTime; }));
         y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.theValue;}));
    
         svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

         svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("return time(ms)");

         svg.append("path")
            .datum(dataset)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);
    });
   
    //~~~ Format The Date:
    function formattedDateTime(dateAndTime) {
        var d = new Date(dateAndTime);
        var numDate = d.getDate();
        var numMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var numYear = d.getFullYear();
        var numHours = d.getHours();
        var numMinutes = d.getMinutes();
        var numSeconds = d.getSeconds();
        numDate = (numDate &#60; 10) ? "0" + numDate : numDate;
        numMonth = (numMonth &#60; 10) ? "0" + numMonth : numMonth;
        numHours = (numHours &#60; 10) ? "0" + numHours : numHours;
        numMinutes = (numMinutes &#60; 10) ? "0" + numMinutes : numMinutes;
        numSeconds = (numSeconds &#60; 10) ? "0" + numSeconds : numSeconds;

        return numYear + "/" + numMonth + "/" + numDate + " " + 
    numHours + ":" + numMinutes + ":" + numSeconds;
    };
```

The first error occurs at the 'dataset.forEach()' function, which is "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`". My effort there to parse that data stems from another error that occurs at the 'svg.append("path")' point in the code, which is "`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…`".

Comment: Hi @WebFixItMan, could you share the data object "dataSet" after you perform the for loop at the top. I believe the main reason for both errors comes from the output of the `formattedDateTime` function.

Comment: What version of D3?

Comment: Hi Alex and Gerardo!
I believe Cyril's reply answers Alex's question. For Gerardo I am using the CDN link:
 `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the date you are passing is in this format:

'2016/07/12 15:58:40'

and the parsedate function you have made to parse it is(Note there is no hyphen in the date):

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
```

it should have been

```
 var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
```

Next bug is, you are passing data for getting the extent, but its not defined anywhere:

```
 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.theTime; }));
 y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.theValue;}));
```

It should have been:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {
  return d.theTime;
}));
y.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {
  return d.theValue;
}));
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qve8nx/)

Comment: Hi Cyril:
Your advice has almost cleared a path to success. It has given me a direction to solve this. I am still getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. My display also worked when I hard coded the variable 'dataset' like your example on JSFiddle. However, in my version I am confined to using the dynamic 'dataset' variable. I performed an `alert(typeof(dataset))` before the 'dataset.forEach' function and it reported it as an 'object'. I am going to start researching how to overcome this, but if you have insight I greatly appreciate the feedback.